# Bootstrap 3 Not XS on iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a very strange error while I'm making my bootstrap 3 website: for some reason it is not adapting to the smaller iPhone screen size (the navbar is not collapsing, and the "col-xs-..." seems to be getting ignored).

I have double checked the screen width on the iPhone (it's 320px), and my website is adapting fine on my desktop at 767px when I resize the browser. Only the iPhone seems to be giving me problems and I don't know how to diagnose the problem.

You can see the website at [www.sparkmyinterest.com](http://www.sparkmyinterest.com)

Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You don't have the meta viewport in your dom-head.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```