# How to force high DPI mobiles to open xs layout in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I'm creating a website with Bootstrap 3, and my iPhone and others mobile devices doesn't recognize the mobile (xs) media-queries.

Since iPhone 4 has a high DPI resolution, it's opening the tablet version, as setted in my media-queries. My navbar isn't collapsing in my phone, so I can't properly access my menu items.

How can I force iPhone 4 and others high DPI devices to open its mobile version?

Comment: Check your viewport settings. As per a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933848/bootstrap-3-not-xs-on-iphone-5): make sure you "You don't have the meta viewport in your dom-head" :

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" `/>

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is designed mobile-first. There is no media query for `xs` size because this is the "default" css. I suggest you to find and replace every media query for, as you called it, "tablet" version.

For example, with Bootstrap default breakpoints:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
```

change to

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
```